# React Class component to Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am converting this Class component

```
class Pricing extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    pricelist: {
      pricelistEntries: [],
      name: '',
      monthlySubscriptionFee: '',
      currency: '',
      validFrom: '',
      smsInPackage: '',
    },
    nextPackage: undefined,
    showNextPackage: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getData } = this.props;
    getData(
      'price-lists/profile',
      { defaultSort, resourceArrayName: 'pricelist' },
      true
    ).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        pricelist: res.data._embedded.pricelist[0],
        nextPackage: res.data._embedded.pricelist[1],
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }

  handleShowNextPackageDetails = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ showNextPackage: !state.showNextPackage }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { pricelist, loading, showNextPackage, nextPackage } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
          <Loading loading={loading} spinner>
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography variant="body1" style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                <FormattedMessage id="administration.packages.form.section.package.info" />
              </Typography>
              <PackageView pricelist={pricelist} />
            </React.Fragment>
          </Loading>
        </Paper>
        {nextPackage && (
          <Paper className={classes.next}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <Typography variant="body1" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <FormattedMessage id="account.packages.form.section.next.package" />
              </Typography>
              <Button
                color="secondary"
                onClick={this.handleShowNextPackageDetails}
                size="small"
                style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}
              >
                <FormattedMessage id="account.balance.details.label" />
                <ExpandMoreIcon
                  className={classnames(classes.expand, {
                    [classes.expandOpen]: showNextPackage,
                  })}
                />
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Collapse in={showNextPackage} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <PackageView pricelist={nextPackage} />
            </Collapse>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

to this Functional component

```
const Pricing = props => {
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState(
    {
      loading: true,
      pricelist: {
        pricelistEntries: [],
        name: '',
        monthlySubscriptionFee: '',
        currency: '',
        validFrom: '',
        smsInPackage: '',
      },
      nextPackage: undefined,
      showNextPackage: false,
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const { getData } = props;
    getData(
      'price-lists/profile',
      { defaultSort, resourceArrayName: 'pricelist' },
      true
    ).then((res) => {
      setInitialState({
        pricelist: res.data._embedded.pricelist[0],
        nextPackage: res.data._embedded.pricelist[1],
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const handleShowNextPackageDetails = () => {
    setInitialState(!showNextPackage);
  };

    const { classes } = props;
    const { pricelist, loading, showNextPackage, nextPackage } = initialState;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
          <Loading loading={loading} spinner>
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography variant="body1" style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                <FormattedMessage id="administration.packages.form.section.package.info" />
              </Typography>
              <PackageView pricelist={pricelist} />
            </React.Fragment>
          </Loading>
        </Paper>
        {nextPackage && (
          <Paper className={classes.next}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <Typography variant="body1" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <FormattedMessage id="account.packages.form.section.next.package" />
              </Typography>
              <Button
                color="secondary"
                onClick={handleShowNextPackageDetails}
                size="small"
                style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}
              >
                <FormattedMessage id="account.balance.details.label" />
                <ExpandMoreIcon
                  className={classnames(classes.expand, {
                    [classes.expandOpen]: showNextPackage,
                  })}
                />
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Collapse in={showNextPackage} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <PackageView pricelist={nextPackage} />
            </Collapse>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );

}
```

However, the button which should change visibility of `nextPackage` isn't working. On class component it works fine, and functional doesn't want to expand content on click. Might it be problem with state of object?
Is there better way to convert this component and how to make `handleShowNextPackageDetails` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set your state like :`setInitialState(!showNextPackage);` you are overriding other state variables as well. So the object becomes: `false`:

Instead use the spread operator in all `setInitialState` since it is an object:

```
setInitialState(is => ({...is, nextPackage: !is.nextPackage})
```

Also, an example for updating pricelist:

```
const addEntry = priceListEntry => {
  setInitialState(is => ({
     ...is, pricelistEntries: [...is.pricelistEntries, priceListEntry]
  }))
}
```

#### Explanation:

Spread operator allows you to change the field you want, leaving others the same. And `is` in `setInitialState(is` is just the current state. So, you preserve current state, other than the field you want to change:

```js
let obj = {name: 'Test', value: 10}
console.log(obj)

obj = {...obj, value: 15}
console.log(obj)

obj = {...obj, newValue: 20}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Adding to this, it's better to use multiple `useState`s than to have one massive one (if you need that maybe it's better to use `useReducer`).

Comment: I would personally go with something like @IsaacCorbrey said, although it is a personal preference :)

Comment: I found I can use `useReducer` like this
`  const [state, setState] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}),
    {
      actionsLoading: false,
    },
  )` ant then ilet `setState` as it it in class component?

Comment: You are correct on the `useReducer` part, but I couldn't understand the second question.

Comment: I'm talking about `this.setState((state) => ({ showNextPackage: !state.showNextPackage }));`
basically all I need with `useReducer` is to remove `this` references?

Comment: @Ati I would read up on [how reducers work](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers) and [React's implementation of them](https://alligator.io/react/usereducer/).